# find & replace in jquery... having issues with an array of search terms

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I'm attempting to find and replace a string of text, but it doesn't seem to like when I reference a variable?  It works fine if I hardcode the number in there, but returns

missing : after property id

if I try to reference a variable:

```
var text = "section-1 section_1 section[1]";
var cloneCount = 1;
var cloneUp = 2;
var array = {
  "section-"+cloneCount:"section-"+cloneUp, 
  "section_"+cloneCount:"section_"+cloneUp, 
  "section\\["+cloneCount:"section\["+cloneUp
};

for (var val in array) {
  text = text.replace(new RegExp(val, "gi"), array[val]);
  alert(text);
}
```

Hoping someone here can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array` initialization is incorrect and should just cause a syntax error. You want this:

```
var array = { };
array["section-"   + cloneCount] = "section-"  + cloneUp;
array["section_"   + cloneCount] = "section_"  + cloneUp;
array["section\\[" + cloneCount] = "section\[" + cloneUp;
```

You can't use an expression as a key in an object literal, if you need to use an expression to build the key then you have to use the `o[...] = ...` syntax.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cDthk/

Comment: +1, but just to be clear `array` is not an array (I know you know, just letting the OP know :))

Comment: @Andrew: That naming (and the broken spacebar) threw me a bit too but I didn't want to get into a terminology war ("associative array" is fairly common for those coming from PHP).

Comment: Thank you so much for (1) showing me and (2) explaining it so nicely... I appreciate it a lot!